# How can I create an efficient bloom shader with GLSL?

Tags: shaders, glsl, bloom

I have searched the net for resources related to rendering a bloom effect using GLSL, but haven't found anything. Although the [tutorial at Philip Rideout's website](http://prideout.net/archive/bloom/) is a good one, it performs very poorly on my Nvidia GPU.

Can anyone guide me as to how should I approach this problem and build a fairly efficient implementation of a bloom effect?

Comment: Ardor3d, an opensource java 3d engine, has a bloom shader implemented. Since it is opensource you can easily check that out (www.ardor3d.com). But basically, its just copying the framebuffer, downscale,blur,additive blending..

Comment: What kind of GPU do you have?

Comment: Very important to let us know what GPU / video card you have. +! @JoshPetrie

Comment: I have a Nvidia GeForce GT 230M graphic card on my laptop

Comment: @snape: Have you considered that maybe the card is what's slow, not the algorithm?

Comment: @snape: I don't own an NVidia card but the GT x30 line tend to be basic general purpose cards, not aimed at gaming enthusiasts.

Comment: @snape:  How large a gaussian kernel are you using, and what is the resolution of your largest blurred FBO?  The easiest way to improve performance is to use a smaller kernel and a smaller FBO.  (In my stuff, I do my blurring inside a 512x512 resolution FBO, no matter the display resolution)

Answer (score 3):

As Trevor mentioned in his comment, your only option might be to reduce the size of your kernel or to perform further downsampling .

But did you thoroughly read the tutorial you've linked to? There's a tip about exploiting hardware filtering, that the author calls the "sneaky" version. It's probably the best trick you can use to optimize you bloom effect without affecting its quality.

Comment: Yes, I read the tutorial thoroughly. I finally improved it's performance by using offline rendering and also I hadn't enabled hardware support for graphics application earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a very similar problem (blurring, but the bloom filter is bluring) with two passes.

In the first pass i blur in the X direction and in the second pass i blur in the Y direction.

I dunno from where i do have this trick but it lowers the time complexity from n² to 2n.

This works only for kernels which don't have any direction (so you can'T optimize a bokeh kernel this way).